# How create ontology with OntoStudio?

Tags: ontology, protege

I need to create a taxonomy and  rdf/xml ontology for it,Initially i started with "Protege"
i found tutorial with sample example,and done with it.

On googling i found OntoStudio is better than Protege,but i am not finding any tutorial with example on creating ontology,

Can any body help me in finding it.

With advance thanks,
Laxmi.P

Answer (score 1):

The Ontoprise company has posted a pseudo video tutorial: http://www.ontoprise.de/fileadmin/user_upload/product-videos/OntoStudio/OntoStudio3-Video.html

Comment: A link with no summary of content is likely to be removed